# Subnational African election results, disaggregated

Tags: data-request, africa, elections

I was wondering if there exists a database that tracts election results in African countries on a disaggregated level. So far, I was unsuccessful in finding one... I would be particularly interested in the elections in North & South Sudan,Cameroon, Liberia, and Mali